# Create a probability model from discrete data

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a set of data about how long a task takes that I expect to be normally distributed (fits a bell curve).  I would like to create a curve/distribution that fits this data as best possible so that I can simulate the task with a computer program.

For example, my data says an individual task took someone 10, 20, 21, 23, and 35 seconds on their various attempts at doing this task.  I'd like to create a function that let's me randomly simulate someone performing this task where the probability of each outcome roughly matches the distribution of the input data.

How would I go about doing this?  Alternatively, what technique should I be searching for that would show me how to do this?  (For reference, I'm a computer programmer too many years removed from college statistics and math courses.  I am having trouble figuring out how to turn the discreet data points into a normally distributed curve that I can feed random numbers to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this kind of problem is very common.

If your hypothesis of a normal distribution, one must calculate the mean and the variance of the sample provided you have enough data (they are estimators of the mean and the variance).
$m = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i X_i$ for the mean and $\sigma²=\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_i (X_i - m)^2$.

Now you must plot your normal function to check if your model is correct (and the squared difference between the model and the sample):

[image: Normal distribution]

Comment: Much appreciated!  It might be a very common problem, but for the life of me I couldn't remember the right terms to search for it properly.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LCC : No problem!